# how to initialise all the value of an array to zero

Tags: c++

In cpp imagine if I am writing like

```
int n;cin>>n;
int a[n]={0};
```

what I am expecting is that this code will convert all the n elements value to zero but instead, this is giving me the error:

> variable sized object may not be initialised

Comment: That's a VLA and VLAs are non-standard C++.

Comment: C++ only supports arrays of compile-time size. Your compiler allows non-standard variable-length arrays (VLAs), but for some reason doesn't want you to initialize them. Better use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

For variable array length use

- `vector<int> a(n, 0);` to both allocate and initialize (I explicitly indicate 0 as the initial value but this is the default), that both allows you to resize and also to ask for the size, check the index is valid when you access it etc. This is the more secure and practical way.
- `new int[n];` then initialize it with 0, but the array size is constant and you have to know the size is *n* by yourself when you use it
- or as in C `(int *) calloc(n, sizeof(int))` allowing to resize it through *realloc*, but you still have to know the size when you use it

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int n = 5;
    int val = 0;

    int arr[n];
    std::fill_n (arr, n, val);
}
```

Do you need something like this?